# YQL framework allowing ajax cross-domain requests is gone?

Tags: jquery, ajax, yql

It seems that YQL doesn't work anymore. All examples just return error alert or nothing.
I tried to execute this code and got nothing as a result:

```
(function ($) {
  "use strict";

  $.queryYQL = function (statement, type, envUrl, callback) {
    if ($.isFunction(type)) {
      callback = type;
      type     = "json";
    } else if (!type.match(/(json|xml)/)) {
      callback = envUrl;
      envUrl   = type;
      type     = "json";
    } else if ($.isFunction(envUrl)) {
      callback = envUrl;
      envUrl   = undefined;
    }

    var scheme = (document.location.protocol === "https:" ? "https" : "http"),
      url = scheme + "://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?callback=?",
      data = {
        format: type,
        q:      statement
      };

    if (envUrl === "all") {
      envUrl = scheme + "://www.datatables.org/alltables.env";
    }

    if (envUrl) {
      data.env = envUrl;
    }

    return $.get(url, data, callback, "json");
  };
}(jQuery));

var statement = "select * from feed where url='http://google.com'";
  $.queryYQL(statement, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

I have nothing to add but StackOverflow forced me to add this line cause 'post need more details'

Comment: I used to be a big endorser of YQL, but nowadays I'm not so sure anymore. If you need production-level reliability, then I don't recommend YQL, as a website needs to add just one line in their `robots.txt` and your YQL app will stop working. With Verizon's purchase of Yahoo, I'm even less sure about YQL now. It's high time to look for a replacement...